# Android: avoid webview refresh in tab fragment

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm creating an app with 2 tabs, one of the tabs contains a `WebView`.
The problem is that every time I switch between tabs, the `WebView` is refreshed.

My structure is:

I created actionbar and to tabs extends fragment

My tab2 class code:

```
public class CopyOfTab2 extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private Fragment mFragment;
    private WebView mWebview ;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab2);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("RH", "in OnCreateView");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab2, container, false);
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        return v;
    }   

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mWebview = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.GalleryWebView);
        //gallery.setAdapter(adapter);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

            mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Log.e("RH","error in web rh");
                    //Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            if (webViewBundle == null) {
                Log.e("RH","webViewBundle null");
                mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");      
            } 
            else {
                Log.e("RH","webViewBundle not null");
                mWebview.restoreState(webViewBundle);               
            }

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        //switchContent("tab2");

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mFragment = new CopyOfTab2();
            // Attach fragment1.xml layout
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
            ft.attach(mFragment);

    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Remove fragment1.xml layout
        //ft.remove(mFragment);
        ft.hide(mFragment);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar approach and is suffering the same problem, because every time the tab is selected a new instance of the fragment is created:

```
mFragment = new CopyOfTab2();
```

Hence everything will be executed again.